# how to make react-native-paper work with next.js?

Tags: next.js, react-native-web, react-native-paper

I installed this example https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-react-native-web and I added react-native-paper to it , when ever I use it ,I get this error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-native'
Require stack:
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/styles/fonts.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/styles/DefaultTheme.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/core/theming.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/index.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/.next/server/static/development/pages/index.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/require.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/load-components.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/api-utils.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js
- /Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:954:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:847:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/styles/fonts.js:1:279)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/amesbahi/Code/with-react-native-web-app/node_modules/react-native-paper/lib/commonjs/styles/DefaultTheme.js:1:282)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:976:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:884:14)
```

here is a copy of my repo [enter link description here](https://github.com/abdullah-almesbahi/with-react-native-web-app)

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days. Hope some one can help me

Answer (score 1):

I had same approach and same issue as yours.
Here is how I made React Native Paper work in Next.js.

1. Build Next.js and React Native for Web(RNW) with Expo.io
   Check this [tutorial](https://dev.to/evanbacon/next-js-expo-and-react-native-for-web-3kd9) and make sure it's running on your local
2. Follow the **[Getting Started](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/getting-started.html)** part and [Using on the Web](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/using-on-the-web.html) in React Native Paper Doc, however, regarding to `next.config.js`, this is all you need to do.

```
const { withExpo } = require("@expo/next-adapter");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withFonts = require("next-fonts");

module.exports = withExpo(
  withFonts(
    withImages({
      projectRoot: __dirname
    })
  )
);
```

Since Expo already provides these build-in plugin to load images and fonts, you don't need to manually add any loader for your webpack, just using it and it should work.

Comment: So we can skip the `CRA`, `Custom webpack setup` and `Configure webpack`?